# How can I do pull-ups in my apartment with thick door trim?

Tags: pull-ups, exercise-equipment, home-exercise

Pull-ups are probably my favorite exercise and I love doing them! However, I recently moved into a new apartment where my trusty old pull-up bar didn't work because the moulding/trim on every door in my apartment is very thick (almost 6 inches). I bought a new pull-up bar that uses pressure to stay up, but it is slowly damaging the frame.

Because I don't own the apartment, installing anything permanent is out of the question.

I was looking into free-standing pull-up bars (which seemed like overkill), but they seemed expensive and way too big to fit into the limited space in my room.

I also found [these pull up bar handles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08PH8PTM1) on amazon, but the reviews mentioned them being very fragile (which obviously won't do if I do a lot of pull ups).

What is the best piece of equipment for me to do pull-ups?

Comment: All door frame pull-up bars destroy the door lining over time. As it is an apartment, you could just repair it before you head out. Bit of putty, and paint can make it look like new unless you are heavy enough to collapse them entirely. If repairing/replacing it is out of the question, your best bet is a free standing pull up bar or find somewhere else to do pull-ups.

Comment: @EricWarburton I think I may have understated the damage to my doorframe (although I certainly will try to fix it). Your comment seems helpful; if you make it an answer I'd probably accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Door frame pull up bars damage the door lining no matter what you do, you can lessen the damage with towels to disperse the load or extra foam padding, but it does not negate the damage entirely.

[image]

Since you are in an apartment, you can just repair it before you head out. Typically a bit of putty and paint will make it look like new so you can get your deposit back. putty won't really restore the structural integrity so it will just fall apart if someone else puts a pullup bar on the same place, but at that point you will be gone. The worst damage I have seen is the lining being torn off the door frame and snapping which could force you to replace the lining all together.

If replacing/repairing the pull-up bar is out of the question I would recommend a freestanding pull-up bar or just finding somewhere outside your apartment to do pull-ups.